# Does Odoo REST API allow login to Odoo Web UI backend?

Tags: java, odoo, odoo-10

I am looking for alternative ways to login to Odoo Web UI backend.

I have google around the internet for alternative ways to login to Odoo web backend.

I am looking on a Authentication Portal to login to all my odoo instance. I am using java as the programming language due to requirements of my project.

I am not allowed to use any social media login methods for this project.

Some of the things which I found:

- To login via /web/login standard login page. (Does not fit my project requirement)
- https://odoo_server_url/web/login?db=db_name&login=username&key=password (Already Removed in Odoo 10 due to its vulnerability)
- Odoo XMLRPC (Only allowed access to Odoo Database only not Web UI level)
- Odoo google OAuth2 Client that only have documentation on how it works with google account
- Free REST API and Oauth2 modules which there are not much documentation on how they work.

Does anyone know of any other ways to login to odoo server web backend without using the /web/login login page?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, no core feature is provided as an alternative to your requirement, but for the backend, some modules are available to auth using REST API.

Below is the link to access free modules for REST API.

https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/browse?price=Free&search=rest+api

This module may help but you need to do some more customization to it:

https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/11.0/smile_api_rest/